# How to use height:50% if the container height is not defined?

Tags: html, css

I would like to use height:50%, but the container's height is not defined, what's the correct solution?

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left-50">
        <div id="left-50-1">1</div>
        <div id="left-50-2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="image">
        <img src="http://automarka.hu/images/stories/Audi%20A8%202.8%20V6%20FSI%202007.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

#container {
    overflow:hidden;
}

#left-50 {
    float:left;
}

#left-50-1 {
    height:50%;
    width:50px;
    background:yellow;
}

#left-50-2 {
    height:50%;
    width:50px;
    background:purple;
}

#image {
    float:left;
}
```

Jsfiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/XqMDF/

Comment: 50% refers to which element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct solution is to define container height.
or refer to the body or other defined element.

make container `display:inline-block;` to adjust to image height ... or define a fixed height.

[DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/XqMDF/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/XqMDF/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Point is: add `position: relative;` to `#container`, and `position: absolute;` to elements with `height: 50%;`. Also, apply `display: block;` to image. Then add left margin on `#image`. Value of that margin is width of elements with `height: 50%;` (50px in your example).

Here is demo with all properties.

http://jsfiddle.net/XqMDF/1/